# System.PlatformNotSupported exception with service stack

Tags: asp.net-web-api, servicestack, httplistener

I am trying to run a service stack application, it works fine on my dev machine when deployed on another box, I get System.PlatformNotSupported exception.
Stack trace below:

Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Operation is not supported on this platform.
   at System.Net.HttpListener..ctor()
   at ServiceStack.Host.HttpListener.HttpListenerBase.Start(IEnumerable`1 urlBases, WaitCallback listenCallback)
  at ServiceStack.Host.HttpListener.HttpListenerBase.Start(String urlBase)
   at ExcaliburAppHost.Program.Main(String[] args)

I am trying to build a Restful app with self hosting (with no IIS support on the other box).

`var listeningOn = args.Length == 0 ? "http://*:8090/" : args[0];
            var appHost = new AppHost()
                .Init()
                .Start(listeningOn);`

error occurs in AppHost().Start() method

Comment: I also tried including System.Web.Http.dll local to the build.

Comment: is it possible to use Apache or NGinx or any other as a HTTP server for any of the .Net web Api project. I am working on the environment where I would have to avoid IIS

Answer (score 3):

If you have any unmanaged .dlls e.g. `sqlite3.dll` you may need to set the **Platform Target** of your project as **x86**.

You can also try running the Console App as Administrator / sudo in-case it's a permissions issue.

Comment: Hi mythz, I am running my app on Windows recovery environment, which is a custom build Win PE image with full .net support. However, I do not have a wifi/networl connection working inside win PE.

My all DLLs are complied x64 and copied locally.

Comment: @rocky test to see if it actually supports [running a basic .NET HttpListener](https://codehosting.net/blog/BlogEngine/post/Simple-C-Web-Server.aspx). If it doesn't you wont be able to use ServiceStack SelfHost which is built on it.

Comment: Support for HttpListener is an issue on that environment so i started looking method inside the calls while creating instance for HttpListener().

I found out call for following unsafe code is returning system status code 1060
`[DllImport("httpapi.dll", ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern unsafe uint HttpInitialize(HTTPAPI_VERSION version, uint flags, void* pReserved);`

meaning of 1060 status code is ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681383(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you have any idea how do we install http API driver (http.sys driver) on a platform? I see on my window 7 and windows 10 it is already installed, but on a custom windows PE (created by us) it is not available, so In case we know the driver we possibly can inject it in our custom PE  image and try it out. Thanks

Comment: @rocky Didn't think it was possible, AFAIK it's in-built into Windows and to get a new http.sys kernel mode driver you'd need to upgrade the OS.

Answer (score 2):

To whom facing with exception "System.PlatformNotSupportedException: ServiceController enables manipulating and accessing Windows services and it is not applicable for other operating systems." - in my case I had to add "System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController" NuGet package to my .net 5 Worker Service project and issue is gone.

Comment: Adding this package `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControlle` brought me to this exception: `System.PlatformNotSupportedException`

Comment: @AdnanAli me as well. Found the solution yet?

Comment: Nopes, I implemented the solution in JS node.

Comment: In my case, I am using .net core 7 and had accidentally updated System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController to preview 9 (which drops support for 7.x), which is as good as not having it installed.

Answer (score 2):

For me, I was building a .NET 6 worker service in a Docker container on a Linux host, building a Windows service to run on Windows Server 2016.  My csproj file has the following properties set, but I was receiving the same PlatformNotSupportedException as the OP:

```xml
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <InvariantGlobalization>true</InvariantGlobalization>
    <PublishSingleFile>false</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishReadyToRun>false</PublishReadyToRun>
```

I was able to resolve this by specifying the runtime option (`-r win-x64`) directly to the `dotnet publish` command in my Dockerfile.

Now the application builds from a Docker container running on a Linux host, but the resulting binaries run fine on the Windows Server 2016 platform.